# Escaping/Unescaping html in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, django, python-2.7

There are many answered questions on stackoverflow about escaping/unescaping html from js. But I am finding it hard to understand as it doesn't fit my context nicely. I have a variable "message" which has this string:

```
message="<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>"
```

I am displaying this message in a js file using "this.message". Instead of seeing the hyperlinked "Google", I can literally see the whole string:

```
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
```

If I inspect element, I can see that this string is being translated into:

```
&lt;a href="www.google.com"&gt;Google;&lt;&gt
```

How do I get the hyperlinked google? Do I have to escape/unescape? How?

Code to display messages:

```
$.each(mdn.notifications || [], function() {
            $('<div class="notification">' + this.message + '</div>')[insertLocation.method](insertLocation.selector);
        });
```

Comment: In your "message" assignment you are showing double quotes within double quotes.  Is that a typo?  Also, what is the code for displaying the message?

Comment: Oops. Please consider "messages" as just an example. In the browser inspect element < shows up as &lt; I just want to prevent that so that my html gets rendered properly. Also check edited question.

Comment: There is a lot I don't understand about your JQuery syntax here, but you might try this: var msg = $.parseHTML(this.message) and then using msg in your JQuery function .

Comment: something similar has to be done. Sorry for asking question poorly. I ll try making it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add html formatting in the django template like this:

```
{% if messages %}notifications: [
                {% for message in messages %}{% if 'wiki_redirect' not in message.tags or waffle.flag('redirect_messages') %}{message: "<div class='my-message'>{{ message }}</div>", tags: "{{ message.tags }}", level: "{{ message|level_tag }}"}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            ],
            {% else %}
            notifications: [],
            {% endif %}
```

Or you can add html formatting in client-side javascript like this:

```
$.each(mdn.notifications || [], function() {
            // Make it so
            $('<div class="notification ' + this.level + ' ' + this.tags + '" data-level="' + this.level + '"><div class="my-message">' + this.message + '</div></div>')[insertLocation.method](insertLocation.selector);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Still getting the same result. inside the dive tag, there is plain text containing a tags. Why marking the message safe doesn't work in this case?

Comment: html is not getting escaped even if mark_safe is used?

Comment: @abhidoeslinux, in that case i'm not sure, maybe use "un-escaping" template blocks like this : {{{ template }}}